# Como alterar o ip do mongo para acesso externo

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Bom atualmente estou usando mongo e react, e como de costume a aplicação funciona no 127.0.0.1

Porém agora também estou com um acesso externo, logo o mongo também deve escutar também de um outro ip externo. Como faço essa mudança?

Pois quando coloco o ip, no moongose nao funciona...

Exemplo

mongoose.connect('127.0.0.1:27017/mydb') Funciona ok aparece as informações..

mongoose.connect('25.10.228.128:27017/mydb')  não funciona

retorna

"
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [25.10.228.128:27017] on first connect'
"

é necessário liberar para que o mongo entenda que tambem deve disponibilizar os dados para quem acessa partir do ip 25.10.228.128 ?

Answer (score 1):

Você deve por o protocolo **mongodb://**
Caso contrário não funciona, mas está certo o que fez, só falta isto mesmo.
Veja um possivel exemplo que talvez serve para ti:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://25.10.228.128:27017:/mydb', {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    user: 'username',
    pass: 'passwrod'
});
```